# Better UI display for popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Is there a better way to display the UI bootstrap popover.

I am currently using the following

[image]

However I would want to use a much bigger popover and this needs to appear on click of each of my row's edit icon...So I would like to somehow keep that context of which row icon is clicked?

How can I achieve a bigger popover and keep the context ?

Can I get to see some sample popover usages ?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code !